# Type '[String]' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'

Tags: swift

I want to use [String] as generic parameter.

```
public class Cell<T : Equatable> {}
```

Here is a line where I get an error:

```
class TagsCell : Cell<[String]>, CellType {
}
```

I've added this code, but it doesn't help

```
public func == (lhs: [String], rhs: [String]) -> Bool {
    return lhs.count == rhs.count && (zip(lhs, rhs).contains { $0.0 != $0.1 }) == false
}
```

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I've tried answers from another questions, and added some code to compare arrays and it doesn't help case [String] still doesn't conform to Equatable protocol

Comment: Please add the code block where you get the error (and indicate the line where you get it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array doesn't conform to `Equatable` in Swift. Conforming to `Equatable` implies there exists `==` operators for this type but not vice verse. Therefore even if you implement `==` for `[String]` type, there's no way you can use `Cell<[String]>`.

In your case, I would suggest using the following protocol:

```
public class Cell<T : SequenceType where T.Generator.Element: Equatable> {}

class TagsCell : Cell<[String]> {
}
```

---

Use a wrapper out of `[String]`:

```
public class Cell<T : Equatable> {}

struct StringArray: Equatable {
    var value: [String]
}

class TagsCell : Cell<StringArray> {
}

func ==(lhs: StringArray, rhs: StringArray) -> Bool {
    return lhs.value == rhs.value
}
```

Comment: It is not good to change the source of the Cell class, cause it's from external library. Is there any solution to make Swift array Equatable?

Comment: @SemyonTikhonenko As far as I know, there's no way to make Array `Equatable` that makes sense. Is it possible for you to use a wrapper out of `[String]`?